# OS X asking for local items keychain password

Tags: macos, password, keychain, filevault, guest-account

My mid-2010 macbook pro was running just fine on OS X 10.10, and then I decided to enable the guest account.

My account still works fine, but when I login into the guest account, I get an annoying dialogue box: `OS X wants to use the "Local Items" keychain. Please enter the keychain password.`

Because this is the guest account, there is no password. So I don't know what to do to get rid of the box.

I tried following the instructions [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread/6317038), by going to Keychain Access Preferences and resetting the default keychain in the guest account, but it just said "Keychain Not Found."

Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be trying to connect to Wi-Fi? Alternatively is there anything you have set to start in the guest account that might need something from Keychain?

Comment: I don't think it is trying to connect to wifi, since my wifi is broken and I don't have any saved wifi passwords anywhere on my Mac. I don't have any login items set, either on my account or on the guest account